# Why is console.log an empty function on some sites in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, dom-events

Go to Twitter's login page and type the following in the console:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){console.log('hello')}, true)
```

(NOTE: how the third parameter is set to `true` which enables event capture. This causes events to be intercepted first by the window before being consumed by a child element.)

Try pressing some keys. Notice how `hello` isn't output to the console. Adding an event listener for `keydown` or `keyup` doesn't change anything.

`hello` will get output on most websites, but not on sites like Twitter or Gmail.

Why? What's stopping the event listener?

EDIT: Seems to work as expected on Firefox. But not Chrome. Why isn't Chrome firing the event listener as expected?

EDIT 2: As deduced by a few people below, `console.log` is an empty function on Chrome for sites like Twitter and Gmail. Why is that?

Comment: Shouldn't you add it to `document` instead of `window`?

Comment: They are probably cancelling the event using `keydown` for some keys.

Comment: Why's that? (And that still doesn't resolve the issue.)

Comment: Er, bit of a race condition on comments (I was replying to Bergi's original comment.)

Comment: I don't have this issue. The handler function gets properly called in both Gmail and Twitter's login pages. Make sure you're focusing out of firebug (or whatever dev console you're using) in your testing.

Comment: @Alexander, I've done that. Could it be a cross-browser thing? What browser were you on? (I'm on Chrome.)

Comment: @Alexander, made an edit. It seems to work as expected on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

Comment: No idea but it only adds to reasons I don't prefer Bootstrap.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because those sites have specifically set (for webkit apparently):

```
console.log = function(){};
```

However, in Chrome you can restore the original `log()` functionality by issuing this command in console:

```
console.log = console.__proto__.log
```

Then you can do this:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){console.log('hello')}, true)
```

And it should work as expected.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue. I made an edit on the original post to clarify - even with event capturing turned on, the listener still isn't being called.

Comment: asked this on another post already: but why is console.log an empty function on Chrome, but not on Firefox?

Comment: But this isn't reproducible on all sites. For instance, Google.com (in Chrome) outputs `hello` on each click.

Comment: Ah. So Twitter's only emptying out the function on Webkit. Strange.

Comment: But **why**? Why would a website purposely break dev tools?

Comment: <3 for "finding `console.log` back"!

Answer (score 3):

Get it from an iframe:

```
function setConsole() {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  console = iframe.contentWindow.console;
  window.console = console;
}
```

(and then call it)

```
setConsole()
```

source: https://gist.github.com/cowlicks/a3bc662b38c36483b35f74b2b54e37c0

Answer (score 2):

Developers like to put `console.log()` statements in their code for troubleshooting/debugging. Sometimes, they forget to take them all out when checking in production code. A simple safeguard against this is to redefine `console.log()` in production code to be an empty function that does nothing so even if a developer accidentally leaves one in, it won't cause any output or throw an exception when there is no `console` object when not running the debugger (like in IE).

Some browsers may protect against the replacing of that function by making it read-only such that it can't be overwritten in this way, but if they do that, then the console object must exist so there's still no harm from an occasional `console.log()` statement.  The main harm of these leftover `console.log()` statements is in IE where it causes an exception to be thrown because the `console` object doesn't exist unless the debugger is being run.

Comment: Except I can manually override console.log just fine on Firefox too. So it can't be a browser specific thing - it must be Twitter specifically targeting Webkit (as canon mentioned)

Comment: They can add an empty function in production code, but they can't remove log statements? Those are some silly developers. Do you think that's really the reason?

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with console.log. try this instead:

```
window.addEventListener('keypress', function(e){alert('hello')}, true)
```

Comment: Interesting. Is console.log forever hosed in this scenario? Is there any way to retrieve its original functionality?

Comment: that still confuses me, though. Why is console.log an empty function on Chrome, but not on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

This problem doesn't occur on Firefox.

I've checked on Chrome and apparently for some reason the Gmail and Twitter pages end up reassigning console.log to an empty function `function () {}`, so your handler gets called but it does nothing. If you try `alert()` instead of console.log, you'll see it working.

Interesting.

Comment: @jfriend00, that sounds to me like The Right Answer.

Comment: @Matm - OK, I put that comment into an answer and removed my comment.

Comment: @jfriend00, er, except I can manually override console.log just fine on Firefox too. It can't be a browser specific thing - it must be Twitter specifically targeting Webkit (as canon mentioned).