# why is console.log not working inside .each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I tried doing the following:

```
$('.not-following').each(function(i, obj) { 
      console.log('test');
});
```

for some reason it keeps on printing the obj instead of test. Any reason why this is? I tried running this on [here](https://twitter.com/Berrybenka/followers)

Comment: Most likely because your selector didn't select anything. `console.log($('.not-following').length)`

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle link or something, your url dosent seem to work

Comment: And post your HTML **here**.

Comment: Is it printing the obj, as in function def ? then @KevinB might be right

Comment: @neoeahit no need for a fiddle, just visit the twitter page I linked above and then copy and paste the code above on your console

Comment: @adit: It requires you to be logged in.  I don't know about others, but I don't feel like logging into twitter to test this out.

Comment: your link goes to twitter login page

Comment: Placing a div with .not-following as the class on a page and your code, it works as expected. Your going to need to give us more information.

Comment: P.S. It's not "printing the obj".  You're seeing the object in the console because that's the *return value* of this function call.  Chrome's console shows you the return value when you enter commands into the console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They overwritten console

```
> console.log.toString()
"function (){}"
```

Comment: so what does this mean? I can't use console?

Comment: As a further proof (and solution), run `delete console.log` and try again. That should blow away the impostor `console.log` and expose the real one.

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611803/why-is-console-log-an-empty-function-on-some-sites-in-chrome

Comment: @adit: It means you can't use `console` on Twitter.  Try running the code on your own site/example.

Comment: Yes this holds true! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It isn't printing the object instead, what you are seeing is the jQuery (array of nodes) that the `.each()` function returns.

The reason `console.log()` is not working is that Twitter has replaced the method with an empty function, as console.log in production is considered bad practice.

If you need to access `console.log` you can delete the 'overridden' version that the Twitter developers have written by invoking:

```
delete console.log
```

The will default console.log back to it's original function.

Comment: Nice, taking @apsillers comment and adding it to your answer. ;)

Comment: To which comment are you referring? (edit) sorry I didn't see the comments on the other answer.

Comment: @DerFlatulator: This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728824/why-is-console-log-not-working-inside-each#comment29311186_19728924 :-D