# JavaScript function default parameter - Strange behaviour

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

That's one of the strangest things I've seen in a while...

I was playing with JavaScript default parameters, and was curious to know if they are resolved taking into account the context of execution of the function.

I prepared this simple test:

```js
var o = {
  a: 42,
  fn(b = this.a) {
    console.log(b);
  }
};

o.fn();
```

As you can see, the answer to my initial question is YES.

And if you copy and paste the snippet into dev tools you'll get the same result... unless you've open dev tools while visiting twitter.com; in that case the result is `undefined`.

I experienced the same behaviour also if the host object is an array

```js
var arr = [
  42,
  function fn(b = this[0]) {
    console.log(b);
  }
];

arr[1]()
```

Do you have any idea why this could possibly happen?

Comment: An array has no concept of `this` as the function isn't called with the array as context. Twitter probably has another function that somehow overwrites yours, or they've changed some prototype or something.

Comment: @adeneo but the second code snippet actually does work.

Comment: So @Bruno what exactly is the question? By *this* in *... why this could possibly happen* do you mean the behavior you see when the loaded page is twitter.com?

Comment: @Pointy - oh, sure it does, I thought it said it didn't work. Should have bothered to click the buttons and try the snippets.

Comment: Does that mean [this is just a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611803/why-is-console-log-an-empty-function-on-some-sites-in-chrome) then, [or this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32801652/how-to-restore-console-log-on-a-web-page-that-overwrites-it)

Comment: @pointy yes... I was surprised of the different output... I should have thought that they may have simply override `console.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twitter overwrites the `console.log` function.

Comment: Just used on console on twitter: 
console.log
function (){}
outside twitter:
console.log
function log() { [native code] }

Comment: He's actually correct. Go to twitter.com and run `console.log('foo')` in the dev console, it will result in `undefined`. If you inspect the `console` object you will notice functions like `info`, `warn`, `log`, etc are all mapped to a "NO_OP" function.

Comment: Sites like Twitter and Facebook worry about scams involving fake "tricks" consisting of code that does awesome things if pasted into the developer console.